# TypeError: Contract should be marked as abstract

Tags: compilation, constructor

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Contract "BaseRegistrarImplementation" should be marked as abstract.
--> Contracts/BaseRegistrarImplementation.sol:7:1:
|
7 | contract BaseRegistrarImplementation is BaseRegistrar, ERC721 {
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Missing implementation:
--> @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol:44:5:
|
44 | constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

While trying to compile this contract (basically the ENS BaseRegistrarImplementation, updated to solidity 0.8.0)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import './BaseRegistrar.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol';

contract BaseRegistrarImplementation is BaseRegistrar, ERC721 {
    // A map of expiry times
    mapping(uint256=>uint) expiries;

    bytes4 constant private INTERFACE_META_ID = bytes4(keccak256("supportsInterface(bytes4)"));
    bytes4 constant private ERC721_ID = bytes4(
        keccak256("balanceOf(address)") ^
        keccak256("ownerOf(uint256)") ^
        keccak256("approve(address,uint256)") ^
        keccak256("getApproved(uint256)") ^
        keccak256("setApprovalForAll(address,bool)") ^
        keccak256("isApprovedForAll(address,address)") ^
        keccak256("transferFrom(address,address,uint256)") ^
        keccak256("safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256)") ^
        keccak256("safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256,bytes)")
    );
    bytes4 constant private RECLAIM_ID = bytes4(keccak256("reclaim(uint256,address)"));

    constructor(ENS _ens, bytes32 _baseNode) {
        ens = _ens;
        baseNode = _baseNode;
    }

    modifier live {
        require(ens.owner(baseNode) == address(this));
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyController {
        require(controllers[msg.sender]);
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Gets the owner of the specified token ID. Names become unowned
     *      when their registration expires.
     * @param tokenId uint256 ID of the token to query the owner of
     * @return address currently marked as the owner of the given token ID
     */
    function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view override returns (address) {
        require(expiries[tokenId] > block.timestamp);
        return super.ownerOf(tokenId);
    }

    // Authorises a controller, who can register and renew domains.
    function addController(address controller) external override onlyOwner {
        controllers[controller] = true;
        emit ControllerAdded(controller);
    }

    // Revoke controller permission for an address.
    function removeController(address controller) external override onlyOwner {
        controllers[controller] = false;
        emit ControllerRemoved(controller);
    }

    // Set the resolver for the TLD this registrar manages.
    function setResolver(address resolver) external override onlyOwner {
        ens.setResolver(baseNode, resolver);
    }

    // Returns the expiration timestamp of the specified id.
    function nameExpires(uint256 id) external view override returns(uint) {
        return expiries[id];
    }

    // Returns true iff the specified name is available for registration.
    function available(uint256 id) public view override returns(bool) {
        // Not available if it's registered here or in its grace period.
        return expiries[id] + GRACE_PERIOD < block.timestamp;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Register a name.
     * @param id The token ID (keccak256 of the label).
     * @param owner The address that should own the registration.
     * @param duration Duration in seconds for the registration.
     */
    function register(uint256 id, address owner, uint duration) external override returns(uint) {
      return _register(id, owner, duration, true);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Register a name, without modifying the registry.
     * @param id The token ID (keccak256 of the label).
     * @param owner The address that should own the registration.
     * @param duration Duration in seconds for the registration.
     */
    function registerOnly(uint256 id, address owner, uint duration) external returns(uint) {
      return _register(id, owner, duration, false);
    }

    function _register(uint256 id, address owner, uint duration, bool updateRegistry) internal live onlyController returns(uint) {
        require(available(id));
        require(block.timestamp + duration + GRACE_PERIOD > block.timestamp + GRACE_PERIOD); // Prevent future overflow

        expiries[id] = block.timestamp + duration;
        if(_exists(id)) {
            // Name was previously owned, and expired
            _burn(id);
        }
        _mint(owner, id);
        if(updateRegistry) {
            ens.setSubnodeOwner(baseNode, bytes32(id), owner);
        }

        emit NameRegistered(id, owner, block.timestamp + duration);

        return block.timestamp + duration;
    }

    function renew(uint256 id, uint duration) external live onlyController override returns(uint) {
        require(expiries[id] + GRACE_PERIOD >= block.timestamp); // Name must be registered here or in grace period
        require(expiries[id] + duration + GRACE_PERIOD > duration + GRACE_PERIOD); // Prevent future overflow

        expiries[id] += duration;
        emit NameRenewed(id, expiries[id]);
        return expiries[id];
    }

    /**
     * @dev Reclaim ownership of a name in ENS, if you own it in the registrar.
     */
    function reclaim(uint256 id, address owner) external live override  {
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(msg.sender, id));
        ens.setSubnodeOwner(baseNode, bytes32(id), owner);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceID) public view override returns (bool) {
        return interfaceID == INTERFACE_META_ID ||
               interfaceID == ERC721_ID ||
               interfaceID == RECLAIM_ID;
    }
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'missing implementation' comes from the fact you didn't make a constructor for your erc721.

It should be:

```
constructor(ENS _ens, bytes32 _baseNode) ERC721("MY_NAME", "MY_SYMBOL"){
        ens = _ens;
        baseNode = _baseNode;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when there are functions you need to implement in your contract from an inherited contract. If the contract does not implement all of the functions it has to be marked as abstract. In your case, the error refers to @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol:44:5, which is the constructor call. Hence, you need to add the constructor of the ERC721 contract such as:

`constructor() ERC721("MyNFT", "MNFT") { }`

See:

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol

[Contract should be marked as abstract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83267/contract-should-be-marked-as-abstract)

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/